# Semantic for encoding geometry-event relation in a spatio-temporal dataset

Tags: geometry, fields-attributes, metadata, spatio-temporal-data

I'm assembling a database of spatio-temporal events; think deforestation for instance.
I have different types of geometries that link to the events in different ways. I would like to encode that meta-information in some way, but I'm lacking the semantic for that.

Here are the geometry - event relations I have:

- A polygon corresponds exactly to the spatial extent of the event
- A polygon contains events but not the entire surface of the polygon is concerned by the events (e.g. A municipality that had some cases of deforestation)
- A point sampled in the spatial extent of the event
- A point loosely linked to the event (e.g. the centroid of a municipality in which there has been deforestation events)

Is there a metadata standard that include this kind of information?
If not, what terms would be suitable to encode these event-geometry relations?
What would be a suitable column name to store that type of meta information?

Comment: I suggest you create your own terminology, ideally in cooperation with users and specialists, and thoroughly document it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Erik, this is definitely an option. Though I feel there's a lot of existing work on geospatial semantics, ontologies and all that and perhaps even a standard

Comment: Have a look at the concept of time space cubes, if this is what you need, see here for a first impression: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/space-time-pattern-mining/learnmorecreatecube.htm or https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/space-time-pattern-mining/create-space-time-cube.htm or https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000017460 - there is much more to find online/in print: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-26772-7_15